# IAR Pragma data_alignment not working

Tags: c, preprocessor, memory-alignment, pragma, iar

I am trying to compile the libvpx library (webm decoder by google) with IAR embedded workbench for an ARM-A7 (bare metal application).

I managed to pull in all the necessary files, and it compiles, but there is a problem with the data alignment of some variables.

In the library, there is a macro DATA_ALIGNMENT() that expands to the GNUC __attribute__(aligned(n)) preprocessor directive. I think I managed to get this macro to work with the IAR version of data alignment (pragma data alignment), but I get the following warning
**"Warning [Pe609]: this kind of pragma may not be used here"**
and when I run the code, my variables are not aligned!

When searching for the warning on the internet, they say you cannot use pragma with definitions of the variables, but only when creating a variable of some kind! However, for data alignment you need to do it when defining the struct (and GCC does allow it, so why wouldnt IAR?)

Any help would be appreciated!

---

**CODE**

*Macro Definitions:*

```
#if (defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__) || defined(__SUNPRO_C)
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED(n, typ, val) typ val __attribute__((aligned(n)))
#elif defined(__ICCARM__)
  #define CONCAT(a,b) a##b
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED(n, typ, val) CONCAT(DECLARE_ALIGNED_,n) (typ,val)
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED_1(typ, val) _Pragma("data_alignment=1") typ val
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED_8(typ, val) _Pragma("data_alignment=8") typ val
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED_16(typ, val) _Pragma("data_alignment=16") typ val
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED_32(typ, val) _Pragma("data_alignment=32") typ val
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED_256(typ, val) _Pragma("data_alignment=256") typ val
#else
  #warning No alignment directives known for this compiler.
  #define DECLARE_ALIGNED(n, typ, val) typ val
#endif
```

*Example where used:*

```
typedef struct VP9Decoder {
  DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, MACROBLOCKD, mb);  
  DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, VP9_COMMON, common);
  int ready_for_new_data;
  int refresh_frame_flags;
  ...
} VP9Decoder;
```

Comment: You should ask the vendor of that library about a standard compliant version. C11 introduced a standard alignment specifier. "so why wouldnt IAR" - Why not ask IAR? After all you (should have) payed a lot of money for their tools. And why not use a modern compiler which appears to work (gcc) anyway?

Comment: I'm doing this for my master's thesis and the company I work with uses IAR, which is why I also use that! I will also ask for help on the google group about libvpx, but thought I'd have more chance of finding someone who had that same warning on IAR on stack overflow.

Comment: Even if, what would that change? The library apparently uses a gcc extension not supported by IAR and the pragma does not work as you expect. So why not go the standard's way or as the vendor why the pragma does not work?

Comment: Well maybe there is a way around it, and I've been thinking about this wrong.. I don't have much experience with (pre)compiler specific settings, so I am not really sure I did the right thing with this macro... Also, an explanation of the data_alignment pragma and it's intended use would be nice, because I am now lost at what it does... If it is not for aligning arrays and structs, then what is it use?

Comment: Ehm, if that library is precompiled, you must **not** change the declaration anyway! (And there comes up a legal aspect: are you allowed to edit the source code of that library at all?). If that is a master's thesis, Why does the company bother if you use a modern toolchain instead?

Comment: The library is not precompiled, I got the sources from github. The library is released under a BSD license so thats no problem either! The company gave me a license for IAR because that is what they use and they already have a software stack (embos, etc.) which i also use!

Comment: IAR for ARM version 8.10 was introduced on Monday which should be fully C11 compliant. The pragma is for aligning data, so for example, you can ensure an array starts on an 8 byte boundary, or a struct starts on a 16 bytes boundary. It has nothing to do with the definition of data types. A data type does not live anywhere, the variable is only aligned when it is created, by using the pragma.

Comment: @Olaf. In the embedded world there does seem to be many different methods of alignment between GCC, IAR, Keil etc which is annoying and hopefully they will go the C11 way and standardize this. However using many different tools chains on a daily basis I would always choose IAR over anything else. It is by far the easiest to use, and the compiler is excellent.

Comment: @RealtimeRik: I strongly disagree about IAR. At least for modern architectures, gcc is much better. And it **does** support C11 for years. The IAR IDE is more of a joke from the 1990ies (but then most IDEs are if you use heavy automation). Considering the costs, gcc and a good build-system like Scons always wins. On ARM, gcc is even better than Keil, although the latter is an ARM company. But then gcc also gets contributions from ARM. Not to forget about the quite "unfriendly" IAR support.

Comment: @Olaf. I'm not going to get into an argument about this as its a matter of personal opinion and what you are using it for. The majority of the work I do is Cortex-M based using Windows. The IAR IDE might not be the best in the world but it is simple to use and reliable and debugging is much better than an eclipse based environment. I used to be a Keil fan, however given a choice, I would choose, IAR, then GCC, then Keil. Be interesting to see where Keil goes now they having started shipping Clang stuff.

Comment: The IDE is indeed a matter of opinion (and I did not say I use Eclipse either - too bloat for me). Just that: try to heavily add automatic code-generation which uses buildinformation (dependencies, etc). For the compiler there are objective measures, though and gcc is clearly ahead (not only for its standard suppport) for ARM at least (I haven't use IAR for other CPUs for a long time). llvm/clang might be worth a try when I have time. Anyway, we seem to agree about Keil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this directly in my IAR compiler (7.40.6) and it works fine:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define DECLARE_ALIGNED(n, typ, val) CONCAT(DECLARE_ALIGNED_,n) (typ,val)
#define DECLARE_ALIGNED_8(typ, val) _Pragma("data_alignment=8") typ val

typedef struct
{
   int a;
   char b;
   char pad1;
   char pad3;
   char pad4;
   int c; 
   char d;  
} myType;

void main( void)
{
   DELCARE_ALIGNED_4( myType, data);
   // So data.a will be aligned to a 4 byte boundary
   // data.b will be aligned to four bytes
   // data.pad, pad1, pad2 are wasted space.
   // data.c will be aligned to four bytes
   // data.d will be aligned to four bytes

}
```

Unless you need to your struct to be in a specific order, for example mapping onto something, then ordering your struct carefully can reduce its size. For example, the padding I inserted in this case would quite likey be inserted by the compiler anyway. The order would be better as `int a, int c, char b, char d.` as the original struct is probably 16 bytes long due to padding and alignment. Whereas it could to be made to be only 12.

Comment: **Ignore previous comment, I didn't pay enough attention to your code!** And how would you align properties of structs? The library aligns different properties of a struct differently... Maybe I could take the biggest alignment value and align every instance of that struct with it? I would lose quite some memory by doing so but if that's the only way.. :/

Comment: I normally do it using padding as if done correctly it should be fully portable.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same, but don't really know how to do that.. How do you know where the struct starts? If eg. the struct is 8bit aligned, how do I know whether I need to add 8 dummy bits to align a property 16bit or if the struct is already 16bit aligned? If you could edit your answer with that explanation I would be really grateful! :)

Comment: If could use DECLARE_ALIGNED_8( your_struct_type, struct_name ); to create a struct aligned on a 8 byte boundary. Note the 8 means bytes, not bits.

Comment: Oh so char don't get aligned even if you use the pragma? Good to know thanks! I'll try this out tomorrow! :)